# Porting C++ OpenGL from windows to mac. What to do with GLKMatrix4MakePerspective?

Tags: c++, opengl, glkit

I am trying to port a c++ program that uses SFML and OpenGL I wrote from Windows to Mac OS X. I am using g++ to compile on both platforms.

Here is my current code for calculating the projection matrix:

```
void perspectiveCalculate (int width, int height) {
    // Prevent A Divide By Zero
    if (height<1) height=1;
    if (width<1)  width=1;
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height); // Reset The Current Viewport
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);    // Select The Projection Matrix
    glLoadIdentity();               // Reset The Projection Matrix
    //field of vision , width , height , near clipping , far clipping
    //and calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
    gluPerspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)width/(GLfloat)height, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);     // Select The Modelview Matrix
    glLoadIdentity();               // Reset The Modelview Matrix
}
```

However, g++ is saying that gluPerspective is deprecated, and I should be using GLKMatrix4MakePerspective instead. I found [the manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKMatrix4/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/GLKMatrix4MakePerspective) on the function but I'm not sure how to integrate it with the rest of my code. What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All your matrix code there is deprecated in modern OpenGL. You can keep using it on the Mac (warnings and all) if you have a GL 2.x context, but if you want to use GL 3.2 or newer you only get a Core Profile context, and for that you need to move to modern OpenGL code. (Ditto if you want to use OpenGL ES 2.0 or newer on mobile platforms.)

In modern OpenGL, the matrix setup functions you're using are all gone. The fixed-function pipeline they go with is replaced by a programmable pipeline... instead of telling OpenGL what model, view, and projection matrices you want and having it do the transformations for you, you do the transformations yourself in a GLSL vertex shader. The good news is that you can now leverage programmable shaders to do all kinds of effects not possible with the fixed-function pipeline. The bad news is you have to do the basic stuff yourself.

Part of doing that basic stuff is finding (or writing) a math library to generate all the matrices you'll be handing off to the vertex shader for doing your transformations. [`GLKMatrix4`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKBaseEffect_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) is part of Apple's library for such things. `GLKMatrix4MakePerspective` takes almost the same set of arguments as `gluPerspective` (vertical FOV *in radians*, aspect ratio, near clipping distance, far clipping distance), but instead of setting fixed-function matrix state it returns a `GLKMatrix4` data structure.

You then pass this data structure to a vertex shader via a uniform variable. Or, if you're working with GLKit anyway, you can look into [`GLKBaseEffect`][2], which provides an Objective-C interface roughly analogous to the old fixed-function pipeline.

Dealing with the entire process of moving to modern OpenGL is beyond the scope of one SO answer. Here's a few resources:

- http://www.opengl-tutorial.org — Good overall tutorial. They use GLM for matrix math, but you can use GLKit math just as well
- [Migrating to OpenGL Core Profile](https://developer.apple.com/opengl/#overlay-video-migrating) — Apple Developer video
- "OpenGL Game" Xcode template — this is for OpenGL ES on iOS, but you can run it in the simulator, and it provides a nice simple example of how to use GLKit to generate matrices and either hand them off to shaders or pass them to `GLKBaseEffect`. The GL part of this is pretty much the same on both iOS and OS X.